# Backbone Subrouter to specific view

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Is it possible to add a subrouter to a specific view? Lets say I have a Backbone app for multiple Cars. Right now, my Router would look like this

```
carRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
   routes: {
      '': 'index'
      'contact' : 'contact'
      ':car': 'car',
      ':car/gallery' : 'cargallery',
      ':car/specs' : 'specs',
      ':car/infos' : 'infos',
      'about: 'aboutPage'
    }

    car: function(){
       // do this
    },
    cargallery: function(){
       // do this
    },
    specs: function(){
       // do this
    },
    infos: function(){
       // do this
    }
    ...etc

});
```

that approach, obviously makes the whole page render, which I basically want to avoid. When I click on "gallery" and "specs" back and forth for example, the whole page re-renders on each click.

So, is it possible to do something like:

```
routes: {
      'contact' : 'contact'
      ':car': 'car',
      'about: 'aboutPage'
      },

     car: function(){
         // new router containing
         // ':car/gallery' : 'cargallery',
         // ':car/specs' : 'specs',
         // ':car/infos' : 'infos',
     },
  }
```

And then, on the Car page, I would have 3 tabs in the menu (gallery, specs, info), which will load the Model/collection of the specific car, without the page re-rendering?

Any help/suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with events,Backbone trigger and and custom EventHandler Object.

The events hash in your CarView :

```
events : {
    "click .spec" : "showSpecs",
    "click .gallery" : "showGallery",
    "click .info" : "showInfo",
},

//Invoked when you click the show specs tab.
showSpecs : function(event) {
//Say that EventBus is your custom event handler
    event.preventDefault();
    MyApp.EventBus.trigger("show:spec",payload); 
},
showGallery : function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    MyApp.EventBus.trigger("show:gallery",payload); 
}
....
```

And in MyApp.EventBus :

```
_.extend(MyApp.EventBus,Backbone.Events);  

MyApp.EventBus.showGallery = function(payload) {
  // payload is an optional data that you can get from the triggered view
  // Fetch your models or collection
  // Instantiate the corresponding view and pass your data(models/collections) to it.
  // Update the url to reflect the new view so that if you hit refresh you
  // come to the same tab.
  MyApp.router.navigate("/your-url",{trigger:false});
}
MyApp.EventBus.on("show:gallery",showGallery);
```

Also add a method in the router  which can handle the refresh of tabs.